# TypeError: element.attr is not a function Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I am using Jasmine and JQuery

I have a simple function like this below which sets attributes to a given element then it returns the element with attributes.

> JS(Jquery)
> appControl.js

```
function setAttributes(element, attributeToAssign, attributeValue)
{
        element.attr(attributeToAssign, attributeValue);

        return element;
}
```

Inside the Jasmine Test file named

> appControl.spec.js
> I have the following Test

```
describe("Set Attributes Test", function()
{
    it("Adds attributes to the passed element and returns it", function()
    {
        //arrange
        var div = "<div></div>";
        var attributeToSet = "class";
        var attributeValue = "tools";

        //act
        var results = setAttributes(div, attributeToSet, attributeValue);

        //results
        expect(results).toBe('<div class="tools"></div>');
        //expect(results).toHaveAttr("class", "tools");
    })
});
```

After running the Jasmine test I get the Following error

```
TypeError: element.attr is not a function in http://localhost/project/js/appControl.js (line 11)
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should wrap the element using **$** to use the .attr() method.
So please replace the method with the following code to resolve the issue.

```
function setAttributes(element, attributeToAssign, attributeValue)
{
        $(element).attr(attributeToAssign, attributeValue);

        return element;
}
```